# Print edges of a cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, graph-traversal, undirected-graph

I have an undirected graph which gets loaded as an adjacency matrix. I have a method to detect a cycle in a graph using BFS algorithm. What I am trying to achieve is to print all the edges in a way that they indicate a cycle which has been found.

I am able to print all the edges in a graph, but I am unable to print only those edges which create a cycle. How do I make it work?

Here is the graph implementation:

Edge:

```
public class Edge {
    int source, dest;

    public Edge(int source, int dest) {
        this.source = source;
        this.dest = dest;
    }
}
```

Graph:

```
public class Graph {
    // A List of Lists to represent an adjacency list
    // Each insideList contains pointers to the next vertex
    // list with an index of 1 (vertex 1) contains elements 2 and 3 (where 2, 3 are vertices connected to 1) 
    List<List<Integer>> adjList = null;

    // Constructor
    public Graph(List<Edge> edges, int N) {
        adjList = new ArrayList<>(N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            adjList.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        // add edges to the undirected graph
        for (Edge edge : edges) {
            int src = edge.source;
            int dest = edge.dest;

            adjList.get(src).add(dest);
            adjList.get(dest).add(src);
        }
    }
}
```

Node:

```
public class Node {
    int v, parent;

    public Node(int v, int parent) {
        this.v = v;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Algorithm and test:

```
public class GraphTest {
    // Perform BFS on graph starting from vertex src and
    // returns true if cycle is found in the graph

    // while traversing the graph, it should display the edges which create a cycle, but I am unable to do it (the result is wrong)
    public static boolean BFS(Graph graph, int src, int N) {
        // stores booleans if a vertex is discovered or not
        boolean[] discovered = new boolean[N];

        // mark source vertex as discovered
        discovered[src] = true;

        // create a queue used to do BFS and
        // push source vertex into the queue
        Queue<Node> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
        q.add(new Node(src, -1));

        // run till queue is not empty
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            // pop front node from queue and print it
            Node node = q.poll();

            // do for every edge (v -> u)
            for (int u : graph.adjList.get(node.v)) {
                if (!discovered[u]) {
                    // mark it as discovered
                    discovered[u] = true;

                    // construct the queue node containing info
                    // about vertex and push it into the queue
                    System.out.println(node.v + " -- " + u);
                    q.add(new Node(u, node.v));
                }

                // u is discovered and u is not a parent
                else if (u != node.parent) {
                    // we found a cross-edge ie. cycle is found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // No cross-edges found in the graph
        return false;
    }
    // Check if an undirected graph contains cycle or not
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // In my case I load an adjacency matrix from file and then perform an action to create Edges.
        // 0 1 1 0 
        // 1 0 1 0 
        // 1 1 0 1 
        // 0 0 1 0

        // Edge(1, 2), Edge(2, 3), Edge(3, 1), Edge(3, 4)
        // Edge(3, 1) introduces a cycle in the graph

        List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrixList = loadFromFile(filePath);
        System.out.println("Graph: (Adjacency Matrix)");
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixList.size(); j++) {
                System.out.print(matrixList.get(i).get(j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("All the edges: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixList.size(); i++) {
            // ' + 1' is added so as to start vertices from 1 instead of 0
            int temp = i + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixList.size(); j++) {
                if (matrixList.get(i).get(j) == 1) {
                    System.out.println(temp + "--" + (j + 1) + " ");
                    // each edge is added one-way only since it is an undirected graph
                    // if Edge(1,3) is already present, Edge(3,1) is not added
                    boolean isFound = false;
                    for (Edge e : edges) {
                        if (e.dest == temp && e.source == (j + 1)) {
                            isFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isFound)
                        edges.add(new Edge(temp, j + 1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // sets number of vertices in the graph
        final int N = 5;

        // creates a graph from edges
        Graph graph = new Graph(edges, N);
        boolean[] discovered = new boolean[N];

        // do BFS traversal in connected components of graph
        System.out.println("Detect a cycle: ");
        if (BFS(graph, 1, N))
            System.out.println("Graph contains cycle");
        else
            System.out.println("Graph doesn't contain any cycle");
}
```

Input: an adjacency matrix (or a prebuilt list of edges)

Current wrong output: displays some edges, but not all the edges of a cycle

Expected output: to print all the edges which create a cycle, as shown in an example above,

I would like to display: `1--2, 2--3, 3--1`
The ending vertex of one edge is a starting vertex of another edge in a cycle.

Comment: Do you want to print all cycles (the number of which can be exponential relative to the number of nodes - see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/number-of-cycles-in-a-graph)), or do you want to print the list of edges that are part of at least one cycle?

Comment: @LiorKogan I'd like to print the list of edges of a single cycle in a specific order (the ending vertex of one edge is a starting vertex of another edge in a cycle).

Comment: @kabugh I am getting issues in writing the main function of the code, can you please help me with the full code of this program? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not claiming this is the best way to achieve the result, but it's one of the ways.

First of all, I'd change the definition of your Node:

```
public class Node {
    int v;
    Node parent;

    public Node(int v, Node parent) {
        this.v = v;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Then in your method BFS, I'd change the boolean array discovered to Node array, so you know, which path leads to this Node.

```
// stores booleans if a vertex is discovered or not
Node[]  discovered = new Node[N];
```

Your BFS method would work then like this:

```
public static boolean BFS(Graph graph, int src, int N) {
        // stores booleans if a vertex is discovered or not
        Node[]  discovered = new Node[N];

        // mark source vertex as discovered
        Node start = new Node(src, null);
        discovered[src] = start;

        // create a queue used to do BFS and
        // push source vertex into the queue
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(start);

        // run till queue is not empty
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            // pop front node from queue and print it
            Node node = q.poll();

            // do for every edge (v -> u)
            for (int u : graph.adjList.get(node.v)) {
                if (discovered[u] == null) {
                    // mark it as discovered
                    Node newNode = new Node(u, node);
                    discovered[u] = newNode;

                    // construct the queue node containing info
                    // about vertex and push it into the queue
                    q.add(newNode);
                }

                // u is discovered and u is not a parent
                else if (u != node.parent.v) {                      
                    Node newNode = new Node(u, node);
                    int commonParent = findCommonParent(discovered[u], newNode);

                    String result = "";

                    Node current;

                    current =  discovered[u];
                    while(current.v != commonParent) {
                        result = current.parent.v + "--" + current.v + ", " + result;
                        current = current.parent;
                    }

                    current = newNode;
                    while(current.v != commonParent) {
                        result = result + current.v + "--" + current.parent.v + ", ";
                        current = current.parent;
                    }
                    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 2);

                    System.out.println(result);
                    // we found a cross-edge ie. cycle is found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // No cross-edges found in the graph
        return false;
    }
```

The method findCommonParent can be implemented for example like this:

```
private static int findCommonParent(Node n1, Node n2) {     
    Set<Integer> n1Parents = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Node temp = n1.parent;
    while(temp != null) {
        n1Parents.add(temp.v);
        temp = temp.parent;
    }       
    temp = n2.parent;
    while(temp != null) {
        if(n1Parents.contains(temp.v)) {
            break;
        }
        temp = temp.parent;
    }

    return temp.v;
}
```

Comment: It works well, but I would like to wait with bounty in case more answers appear so as to then choose the best one :)